# simplexml_load_file return empty object for alexa rank

Tags: php

I'm trying to get alexa rank for any domain, I have found one function it works but if a website not registered on alexa it will return empty object and then my site will stop loading.

Alexa function:

```
<?php
/**
 * Get Popularity Text of a Domain via Alexa XML Data
 *
 * @return string|FALSE text or FALSE on error
 */
function alexa_get_rank($domain)
{
    $alexa = "http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=s&url=%s";
    $request_url =  sprintf($alexa, urlencode($domain));


    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
    if (!$xml) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $nodeAttributes = $xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes();
    $text = (int) $nodeAttributes['TEXT'];

    return $text;
}
```

EX: http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=anythinghere123.com

result:

```
<ALEXA VER="0.9" URL="anythinghere123.com/" HOME="0" AID="VruOh1YRg600iz" IDN="anythinghere123.com/">
<RLS PREFIX="http://" more="0"></RLS>
<SD TITLE="A" FLAGS="" HOST="anythinghere123.com"></SD>
</ALEXA>
```

I tried to give prefixed namespace but it return 0 at all the time (all of domains).

how to solve this problem? I would like to put alexa rank 0 for any website that nor registered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
if (!$xml) {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Replace with this

```
if (!isset($xml->SD[1])) {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: it returns 0 for all domains :(

Comment: Why for all domains? I tried `echo alexa_get_rank('http://google.com');` it returns `2` but not 0

Comment: if I use your code, it returns empty object. I tried that many times just now.

Comment: Okay if the domain without 'www' it will return empty. could hepl me on that?

Comment: For example, I write `echo alexa_get_rank('http://google.com');` this output `2`. How you can see, I use URL without `www`

Comment: Thanks Winston, it works with this code

    `if (!isset($xml->SD[1])) {
            return FALSE;
        }`
thank you again!